# The parameters of the function specify several functions type In Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is my code, I don't known how to write! I feel dinstinctly complex!!Please help me, Thank you!!

```
 interface IMethods {
  aa(): number;
  bb(): boolean;
  cc(): string;
 }

const methods: IMethods = {
  aa: (): number => {
    return 0;
  },
  bb: (): boolean => {
    return false;
  },
  cc: (): string => {
    return '';
  },
};

// what type??
function Demo(func: ???) {
  func();
}

Demo(methods.aa); // expect true
Demo(function other() {}); // expect error!!!!
```

I think of a way, like this.

```
function Demo(func: IMethods[keyof IMethods]) {
  func();
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to treat certain functions (those from `methods`) as special, to make their type indicate that they're more than just functions, and Typescript allows us to do just that. The basic idea of what you want is called the [newtype pattern](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype) (named after the keyword `newtype` in Haskell). Typescript gives us a couple of ways to implement this pattern, and I'm particularly fond of using [intersection types to do so](https://kubyshkin.name/posts/newtype-in-typescript/).

First, we need a type that's impossible for someone to accidentally implement. If we make an interface, then no matter what we put in it, it's still possible for a user to accidentally satisfy it. So we'll make a class with a private member, which forces the type to [be nominal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private). Effectively, that means only *actual* instances of the class are treated as members of the type, not other objects that happen to have the same shape.

```
class NominalClass {
  private _tag: object;
}
```

Now we're going to lie to the type system a bit, to get the guarantees we want. The type `() => T` is too general; it would allow any function, including the ones you want to disallow. So we're going to make a new type that effectively says "I'm basically a function, but I'm special". In Haskell or Scala, we might wrap the function in a new type altogether, but Typescript can do one better: intersection types.

```
type FromIMethods<T> = NominalClass & (() => T);
```

`FromIMethods<T>` is the type of all things that are both `() => T` *and* `NominalClass`. Notably, any instance of `FromIMethods<T>` is *still* a function and can be called with ordinary Javascript function call syntax.

Obviously, your functions aren't `NominalClass` instances, and indeed no function is a `NominalClass` instance, so the type is basically uninhabited. This is where we lie to the type system. We're going to claim to have instances of this type, and Typescript is going to believe us. Your `IMethods` interface will need to be modified slightly.

```
interface IMethods {
  aa: FromIMethods<number>;
  bb: FromIMethods<boolean>;
  cc: FromIMethods<string>;
}
```

Like I said, they're still functions, so we can still call them. We're just adding a bit of structure to them. Now we lie to the type system. We say "I have a way to make an ordinary function into a `FromIMethods`", which is of course impossible, but Typescript doesn't care.

```
function toIMethod<T>(mthd: (() => T)): FromIMethods<T> {
  return mthd as FromIMethods<T>;
}
```

Lastly, we wrap up your `methods` const in a few `toIMethod` calls.

```
const methods: IMethods = {
  aa: toIMethod((): number => {
    return 0;
  }),
  bb: toIMethod((): boolean => {
    return false;
  }),
  cc: toIMethod((): string => {
    return '';
  }),
};
```

And we code `Demo` to take a `FromIMethods<T>` and return a `T`.

```
function Demo<T>(func: FromIMethods<T>): T {
  return func();
}
```

And it works exactly like we want.

```
Demo(methods.aa) // True
Demo(function() {}) // Error
```

Now it's impossible for the user to accidentally pass an ordinary function to `Demo`; they *must* pass a function that came from `methods`. Of course, it's always possible for a malicious user to circumvent your type safety by casting

```
Demo((function() {}) as FromIMethods<void>)
```

But that's always true in Typescript for any types and any function, so it's not really worth worrying about.